# Is it possible to bypass shared library dependencies required for an already-compiled executable?

Tags: linux, shared-libraries

I know there are many ways to remove/add library dependencies reported prior to compiling an executable for use in Linux. However, after a bit of searching I have not been able to find the way to bypass these dependencies when given only the executable and no binaries. For example, if I run ldd on the executable and there is a shared library that is not found and I do not think is necessary for the program to run.

Thank you

Comment: If there's a library dependency reported by `ldd`, then that executable needs symbols from that library.  You may be able to make your own "fake" library that resolves those symbols, and point the executable to it with `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, but you really need to know what you're doing.

Comment: Also, you can use weak linkage (but then the executable needs to be compiled with weak linkage enabled, specifically.)

Comment: @JoeZ "If there's a library dependency reported by ldd, then that executable needs symbols from that library." -- that statement is *incorrect*.

Comment: @EmployedRussian : Ok, it's possible for a library to show up in the `ldd` list and not be needed.  I haven't seen it happen in my experience.  Your answer below, though, does provide a way to test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For example, if I run ldd on the executable and there is a shared library that is not found and I do not think is necessary for the program to run.

You can *trivially* test whether your belief is correct: create an empty "stub" shared library with the name that `ldd` reports as not found, and test whether the executable runs correctly when you make use of that stub (e.g. via `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`).

If the executable does in fact work (which is somewhat unlikely), you can binary-patch the `.dynamic` section of the executable to remove the unnecessary dependency -- `.dynamic` is simply a fixed-sized table of `Elf{32,64}_Dyn` records, terminated by a record with `.d_tag == DT_NULL` (the needed libraries are represented by records with `.d_tag == DT_NEEDED`. You can therefore find the unnecessary record, and simply "slide" all following records one slot up in the table.

Comment: How can I actually edit the .dynamic section? Do you have any recommendations?

Comment: This "stub" method doesnt necessarily work - in my case, the binary still complained that the libary was "too short" afterwards. But when removing it with `readelf` as Chaim suggested below, everything is fine.

Answer (score 2):

You could try patchElf, which is claimed to be "A small utility to modify the dynamic linker and RPATH of ELF executables"

Home page: http://nixos.org/patchelf.html.
github repository: https://github.com/NixOS/patchelf